# Eclipse juno + cuda plugin error

Tags: eclipse, plugins, path, cuda, makefile

I am using Eclipse Juno parallel version. I have installed
cuda plugin. But while building a sample cuda helloworld
program I am getting error -

```
    make all      
    make: *** No rule to make target `exe_cuda', needed by `all'.  Stop.      

    ******Makefile snapshot************** 
     all: exe_cuda   

    # Tool invocations             
@echo 'No tool found that can build the extension specified with the build       
    artifact name $@'         
    # Other Targets    
    clean:     
-$(RM) $(OBJS)$(C_DEPS) exe_cuda    
-@echo ' '
```

Any suggestion......

Comment: Which eclipse plugin are you referring to exactly?  Is it designed to work with juno (eclipse 4.x) ?  The ones I see are set up for eclipse 3.x  You could also try using [Nsight Eclipse Edition](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/nsight-eclipse-edition-getting-started-guide/index.html) which is a separate, stand-alone tool.

Comment: Even I am getting the same error with ECLIPSE HALIOS and CUDA Plugin (Helios) 1.1

Comment: I did a clean install of eclipse helios and the cuda plugin for eclipse helios and had no trouble building and running the sample hello world cuda project.  When I created the project, I did File...New...C++ Project...Hello World CUDA Project   Is that the sequence you used?

Comment: Thank you sir for your kind help, yes it works with c++ Project but I am getting this problem with c project .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree that the toolchain does not appear to be set up properly for C projects.

My suggestions are:

- Create a C++ project instead.  That seems to work.
- Use [Nsight Eclipse Edition](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/nsight-eclipse-edition-getting-started-guide/index.html) instead.  It is installed automatically with the linux CUDA 5 package (just type `nsight` from a terminal window).
- You could report the problem to fixstars corporation, the developer of that cuda plugin.  It seems they have not updated it since 2011, so I don't know if it's actively maintained.  But the help page is [here](http://ydl.net/eclipse_cuda_plugin/userdoc.shtml) which includes a link for a mailing list you could use.