# Executing cuda program through Eclipse is giving error

Tags: eclipse, cuda, linker

I am using eclipse to execute a cuda program. I have downloaded a CUDA PLUGIN for
eclipse. When I execute sample cuda program given by plugin its fine but when I try
to execute  any other program I am getting error undefined reference to main...

```
make 
Building target: Add_cuda
Invoking: NVCC Linker
nvcc -L/export/trainee3/dinesh/cuda5.0/lib64 -o  "Add_cuda"  ./mycuda.o   -lcudart
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.1.2/../../../../lib64/crt1.o: In function `_start':
(.text+0x20): undefined reference to `main'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

I found in stackoverflow that some times we get this problem because of system startup file 
I used flag -nostartfiles but it is not working in my case..

I have included lib64 and include path in c++ build.

So any suggestion to over come this problem....

Comment: possible duplicate of [Eclipse juno + cuda plugin error](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16161212/eclipse-juno-cuda-plugin-error)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We've been [over this already](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16161212/eclipse-juno-cuda-plugin-error).

Use [nsight eclipse edition](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/nsight-eclipse-edition-getting-started-guide/index.html) instead.

If you have cuda 5.0 or 5.5 installed, just type `nsight` in a terminal session.

If you really want to use that Eclipse CUDA plugin (which is no longer supported, I don't believe), then start with the C++ sample project, which you agree now and back then would work.  Then modify the source code in that project.  Don't create your own project.

Answer (score 1):

Install CUDA 5. It comes with `Nsight Eclipse` version. Very Elegant to use. NV Visual profiler is integrated with Nsight. Syntax highlighting and debug mode are very easy to use.